# where to paste the java file into the android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android studio.I am doing the "Send Data From Android To SQL Server Using RESTful API" using Visual Studio and Android Studio.

There is a one instruction that i do not understand is that

- Copy and paste the RestAPI.java file into your project.

I have to copy the RESTAP.java file into my Android studio project but I do not know where should i put inside my android studio (eg., file path location).

below attached is the screenshot that i just create in Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: put with MainActivity

Comment: drag and drop in the first sub-folder under "java" folder

Comment: @AndroidGeeks Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Pooya Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Paste it in the folder containing the MainActivity. Normally the package name would change automatically in Android Studio but if it doesn't then remember to change the package name appropriately.

You can also create a new folder to store all the java files to segregate your API from your main code. That will be just be like another package in your android studio.